# What's the difference between node and peer?

Tags: nodes, peers

I'm confused between the two objects.

As I know, peer is the object or node.

But when we create an Ethereum network, at each node, I have to add a peer.

So it means there is a difference between node and peer.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

It's a language thing about the relationship. It's like "people" and "friends". It's not that friends aren't also people. We might say that people are friends because they have a certain relationship to us.

Ethereum nodes are initially alone, and then they seek out other nodes to talk to. When nodes agree to talk, they become peers to each other.

"Peers" is another word for a person just like me with similar knowledge and abilities. A node's peers are other nodes that work the same way. Nodes talk to the network through their peers, and learn about the network from their peers.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

*In my opinion* : a network node is a connection point(endpoint) that can receive, create, store or send data along distributed network routes. In Ethereum it could be full or Lightweight.

in case of Ethereum, Peer is another term for node but referring the direct connectivity between nodes, because we are using a p2p network in which nodes are connected and share resources without going through a separate server.*

we could have nodes in a centralized system but we will not call them peers.

Comment: Agree with this definition.

Answer (score 1):

A single pc can be a node, suppose you and I both have two pc/nodes. whenever a single node communicate with another node, those are called peer for another. my node is a peer for your node and vice-versa.